# Search query alteration not working for meta values

Tags: wp-query, query, search, pre-get-posts

The bellow code works on category archive pages, it filters out the necessary products. But on the search page it doesn't work. If I uncomment the line `//$query->set("s", "chelsea");`, then on the search page it *does* show the results for that search term. But the rest of the query, that is the meta query and tax query, are not working on the search page.

This is my query alteration code:

```
//Alter query to exclude posts that are outdated, or whose category is hidden
function mts_alter_query($query){

    if(($query->get("post_type") === "product" && !is_admin() && !$query->is_singular()) || ($query->is_search() && !is_admin())){

        //$query->set("s", "chelsea");
        //Hide outdated posts
        $query->set("meta_key", "match-date");
        $query->set("meta_value", date("Y-m-d"));
        $query->set("meta_compare", ">");

        //Hide posts that belong to a hidden category

        $hidden_cat_ids = get_hidden_category_ids();

        $original_tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query', [] );

        $query->set("tax_query", array(
            array(
                "taxonomy" => "product_cat",
                "field" => "term_id",
                    "terms" => $hidden_cat_ids,
                    "operator" => "NOT IN"
                ),
            $original_tax_query
        ));
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mts_alter_query', 999);
```

Comment: That Tax query is stupendously slow/expensive, `NOT IN` queries are one of the worst things you can do in WordPress for slowing down queries and making your site slow at scale. They involve copying the full table into memory to create temporary tables. It would be faster to list every single product cat except the ones you want. for reference, never add checkboxes to hide things from an archive, instead add checkboxes to _show_ things that are checked by default. "include posts in X Y Z" can be thousands of times faster than "all posts except posts in W" despite giving the same results

Comment: how have you implemented your search? Is it standard WP search using `?s=term` or have you got a custom template with a custom `WP_Query` and form?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm not sure, as I'm not the only one developing the website. How can I check? These are the GET parameters I get when I do a search : `?s=Arsenal&jet_ajax_search_settings=%7B%22search_source%22%3A%22product%22%2C%22results_order_by%22%3A%22relevance%22%2C%22results_order%22%3A%22asc%22%2C%22search_in_taxonomy%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22search_in_taxonomy_source%22%3A%5B%22product_cat%22%5D%7D&post_type=product`

Comment: it should be relatively obvious by looking at the search page wether it's a custom template, or standard WP search with a standard main loop and a `search.php` in the theme. Your example does show `jet_ajax_search_settings` which throws a massive spanner in the works, and means you may not be able to get an answer here that works for you, even if it's correct, there's a very high chance you need a Jet search specific solution

Comment: if you are indeed using https://crocoblock.com/plugins/jetsearch/ then your question would be offtopic, and you would never be able to apply a generic WP answer to your problem. Likewise if you're using Elementor to construct your search page as that would bypass the main post loop rendering your filter ineffective

Comment: @TomJNowell then how come setting the search query param works? I am talking about this line - `$query->set("s", "chelsea");`

Comment: @TomJNowell also on other pages (also built with Elementor), the query alteration works fine.

Comment: you've provided no information about how your search page is built, including even the URL of a search would yield a lot of information. Please update your question with the missing information. You can use the `Edit` link under the tags to ensure your question contains all the information you have to help someone write an answer. Including any search related plugins you are relying on, and details of where and how you built it. If this is not a standard general WordPress search archive then there's a very high chance this question cannot be answered here and would be closed as offtopic